# Is $e^z$ a conformal mapping if the domain is $-\pi \leqq\mathrm{Im}\, z<\pi$

Tags: complex-analysis

My text gives an example of a conformal mapping :

> **Example.** The exponential function $e^z$ is conformal at each point $z\in\mathbb{C}$, since its derivative does not vanish at $z$. Its image is the punctured plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. However, it is not a conformal mapping of the plane onto the punctured plane, since it is not one-to-one. Its restriction to the horizontal strip $\{|\mathrm{Im}\,z| <\pi\}$ is a conformal mapping of the strip onto the slit plane $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$.

I was wondering whether we still have a conformal mapping if we change the domain from $-\pi \leqq\mathrm{Im}\, z<\pi$ so the mapping is to the entire complex plane minus the origin. This is still a one to one map and I believe the partial derivatives are continuous. I hope this is not a bad question. I am just asking because very small changes in the domain can change the continuity or differentiability of complex mappings.

Answer (score 2):

It's customary to assume the domain of a conformal mapping is open.

For one thing, differentiability (strictly speaking) assumes an open domain.

For another, a conformal bijection of an open set has conformal inverse. Consequently, there is an induced equivalence relation on the set of connected open subsets of the plane, and conformally-equivalent sets are diffeomorphic. If we allow the half-open strip example, we lose something: The inverse mapping from the punctured plane to the half-open strip is not even continuous, much less conformal, and the forward mapping is not a homeomorphism.

Despite the exponential map being "formally conformal" on the half-open strip, there are costs of utility in allowing this as an example of a conformal mapping. (By analogy, we do not define $1$ to be prime, because doing so would require most theorems about primes to explicitly exclude $p = 1$ from the hypotheses.)